React Native FlatList Horizontal Scroll Not Working with Gesture Handler Pinch Zoom on Android Tablet (Android 14)
I am using a horizontal FlatList combined with react-native-gesture-handler to implement pinch-to-zoom functionality. The pinch gesture works as expected, allowing me to zoom in and out of the content. However, the horizontal scroll of the FlatList is not working properly.
Problem:
Initially, scrolling does not work when zoomed out.
Scrolling starts working only after zooming in significantly.
 <NativeViewGestureHandler disallowInterruption={true}>
      <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onContainerLayout}>
        <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handlePinch} onHandlerStateChange={handlePinchEnd}>
          <View style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
            <Animated.View style={[animatedStyle]}>
              <FlatList
                data={[{ labels, bars }]}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}
                scrollToOverflowEnabled
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `label-${index}`}
                horizontal
                onTouchStart={() => setOuterScrollEnabled(false)}
                onTouchEnd={() => setOuterScrollEnabled(true)}
                onTouchCancel={() => {
                  setOuterScrollEnabled(true);
                }}
                onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
                onMoveShouldSetResponder={() => true}
                onScroll={onScroll}
                nestedScrollEnabled
                decelerationRate="fast"
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  return (
                    <View style={[styles.timelineContainer, { minWidth: xScale(to!) }]}>
                      <View style={[styles.timeLabelsContainer]}>{renderLabels(item.labels)}</View>
                      <View style={[styles.barsContainer]}>{renderBars(item.bars)}</View>
                    </View>
                  );
                }}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          </View>
        </PinchGestureHandler>
      </View>
    </NativeViewGestureHandler>

What I’ve Tried:
Updated react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated to the latest versions.
Wrapped the entire FlatList inside a GestureHandlerRootView.
Checked that scrollEnabled is dynamically set based on the zoom state.
Verified that the contentContainerStyle of the FlatList is correctly set.

Did you ever solve this?

did you resolve it ??
